# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Boa tarde.

Fiz um for para ser verificado alguns valores e me dar um retorno para me mostrar quais valores se encaixam dentro do padrão estabelecido e quais não estão.

o final do código é esse:

```
if (residual < down):
    regl_13[ticker] = {'long': 1, 'short': 0}

elif (residual > up):
    regl_13[ticker] = {'long': 0, 'short': 1}

else:
    regl_13[ticker] = {'long': 0, 'short': 0}

regl_13 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(regl_13, orient='index')
print (regl_13)
```

porém está dando o erro abaixo:

> if (residual < down): ValueError: The truth value of an array with
> more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Para cada item que se encaixe nos padrões do algoritmo o resultado é 1 para long ou 1 para short, caso não se enquadre, ficaria 0 no long e no short.

Como faço para arrumar esse erro?

Obs.: O valor do resíduo geralmente varia entre números como 0,8357 , 0,14045 , -1,2300, etc.

Comment: Qual o type de `residual` e `down`? Parece que, pelo menos um deles, é um array.

Comment: residual = <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
down = <class 'numpy.float64'>

Comment: Não é possível comparar diretamente um array com um float.

Comment: eu consigo transformar array em float? pelo menos o ultimo valor que aparece? pq os valores são diarios, eu poderia pegar o valor do dia atual ou do ultimo dia e transforma-lo em float?

Comment: Acredito que possa ser `residual[len(residual)-1]` ou `residual.tolist()[-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui achar o erro um dia após publicar a questão. Era uma questão de lógica apenas, nada complicado.

Resolvi colocando o código da seguinte forma:

```
if (residual[-1] < down):
regl_13[ticker] = {'long': 1, 'short': 0}

elif (residual[-1] > up):
    regl_13[ticker] = {'long': 0, 'short': 1}

else:
    regl_13[ticker] = {'long': 0, 'short': 0}

regl_13 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(regl_13, orient='index')
print (regl_13)
```

Dessa forma, pegamos os ultimos dados do **RESIDUAL**, já que ele atualiza todos os dias.

E pegamos o dado **UP** e **DOWN**, que são dados únicos, ou seja, não possuem vários dados dentro dessas variáveis, para nos retornar conforme o código propõe.